# Bootstrap 3 data-target attribute on tab not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-tabs

I am using Bootstrap tabs in my website. When page loads tab will be filled with data at run-time using dynamic content. I am using `data-target` attribute on anchor tag for that, but it does not seems to work at all.

Here is what I tried so far:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
            <li role="presentation" class="active">
                <a href="showTab1.do" data-target="#test_1" aria-controls="test_1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 1</a>
            </li>
            <li role="presentation">
                <a href="showTab2.do" data-target="#test_2" aria-controls="test_2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 2</a>
            </li>
            <li role="presentation">
                <a href="showTab3.do" data-target="#test_3" aria-controls="test_3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 3</a>
            </li>   
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="test_1"></div>
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="test_2"></div>
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="test_3"></div> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here I am trying to load content of remote file `showTab1.do` inside div with `id="test_1"` when using `data-target="#test_1"` on anchor tag. But it is not working. What I know is if I am using **data-target** we don't need to write any jQuery/JavaScript to load data in tab as data-target will do that for us(correct me if I am wrong). 
My Bootstrap version is v3.3.6.

Please correct me where I am wrong.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to automatically `load` data from another url into the tab content using data attributes. You'd need to fire the jQuery `load()` method when the show tab event fires...

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function (e) {
  ...

  $(target).load(url,function(result){      
    ...
  });
});
```

Example:
http://codeply.com/go/xZfTnAtKUM

Comment: Hey I just tried this way but it did not worked for me. But when I debug script I found it is able to get remote content but when we do `tab.tab('show');` it does not displayed anything.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML :**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
            <li role="presentation" class="active">
                <a href="#test_1" aria-controls="test_1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 1</a>
            </li>
            <li role="presentation">
                <a href="#test_2" aria-controls="test_2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 2</a>
            </li>
            <li role="presentation">
                <a href="#test_3" aria-controls="test_3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 3</a>
            </li>   
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="test_1"></div>
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="test_2"></div>
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="test_3"></div> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and load the tab content using jQuery load

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#test_1').load('showTab1.do');
    $('#test_2').load('showTab2.do');
    $('#test_3').load('showTab3.do');
});
</script>
```

Comment: I am confused because why just having data-target on link does not loads data there ? I have had done like this in the past without writing any jquery.

Comment: Do you have any link or can you share the code which worked in the past

Comment: Hi Rahul, I tried way you mentioned above and wrote JavaScript to load dynamic data. But in my case when I click on Tab2, browser keeps on loading and does not load data there

Comment: Checkout @Skelly example

Comment: I just tried @Skelly example but no luck. When I debug script I found it is able to get remote content but when we do `$(this).tab('show')` it is not showing anything.

Answer (score 0):

There were a couple of errors but this works. I added the Tab 1,2 and 3 to the tab panes so you can see the result when you click the nav links (jsut remove the text so it doesn't mess up your flow)..

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
            <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#test_1" aria-controls="test_1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 1</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#test_2" aria-controls="test_2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 2</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#test_3" aria-controls="test_3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 3</a></li>   
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="test_1">Tab 1</div>
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="test_2">Tab 2</div>
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="test_3">Tab 3</div> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps - and then load the data into the tab panes using the .load() method as described below.

Comment: There is no .load() method as you described in answer above. But I realize what you meant to say about. I am confused because why just having data-target on link does not loads data there ? I have had done like this in the past without writing any jquery.

Comment: Hi - sorry - I meant the .load() as described by @Rahul Chandrasekharan (who posted the answer before me). You could use the data-target attribute to identify the id of the tab you wish to toggle or just use the href to indicate it, but you cannot use that attribute to load external content into the tab pane div. For that yuo will need to use the .load() method. Hope this helps.